# How to make circles in a panel not touch the borders? (Java Graphics)

Tags: java, graphics, panel

I would like to create circles with a random diameter, position and color in a panel with the Graphics class in Java. It works fine, however I have the problem that often circles touch or overlap the border.

How can I make the circles fully stay within the panel?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code I use for creating the circles:

```
amount = rnd.nextInt(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        x = (50 + rnd.nextInt(panel.getWidth() - 50 + 1)) - 50;
        y = (50 + rnd.nextInt(panel.getHeight() - 50 + 1)) - 50;
        diameter = (rnd.nextInt(100));
        gr.setColor(new Color(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)));
        gr.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
        gr.drawString("" + (panel.getHeight() - y), x, y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    x = (50 + rnd.nextInt(panel.getWidth() - 50 + 1)) - 50;
    y = (50 + rnd.nextInt(panel.getHeight() - 50 + 1)) - 50;
    diameter = (rnd.nextInt(100));
```

How can you calculation the x/y position if you don't know what the diameter of the circle is going to be?

First you need to calculate the diameter. Then you need to use the diameter to make sure the x/y plus the diameter is less than the width of the panel.

I don't understand the point of adding 50 and then subtracting 50. I would think the random number should be the width minus the diameter.